# How to retrieve auth cookie on serverInit in Pinia store?

Tags: firebase, authentication, nuxt3

I have recently started learning Nuxt 3 by trying to implement basic user auth logic with firebase and now I would need to retrieve the cookie from the `req` to initialise the user auth state inside Pinia store but it seems like `nuxtServerInit` is not supported by Pinia. After realising this I proceeded to a different solution where I'm using server middleware to pass the `req` object to an action called `nuxtServerInit()` but then I ran into another problem which is that I cannot call the `auth().verifyIdToken(token)` from there because the firebase is initialised inside a plugin which runs afterwards.

After this I also tried to initialise firebase inside server middleware and pass auth object to `nuxtServerInit()` action and set it to the state but then I could not call an action from there I guess because Pinia has not initialised yet?

How could I overcome the original problem? What could be a better approach?

Heres the firebase init plugin:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useStore } from '~/store/index.js'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "API_KEY",
        authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
        projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
        storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
        messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
        appId: "APP_ID"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const auth = getAuth(app)
    const firestore = getFirestore(app)

    nuxtApp.vueApp.provide('auth', auth)
    nuxtApp.provide('auth', auth)

    nuxtApp.vueApp.provide('firestore', firestore)
    nuxtApp.provide('firestore', firestore)

    const store = useStore()

    console.log('AUTH', auth)
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        store.setAuth(user)
    })
})
```